# Is there a standard way to listen for an on change event of a posts featured image

Tags: plugins, javascript

I'm working on an artist plugin which lets you upload/create a [depth map image](https://www.google.com/search?q=depth%20map&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXrPbpvavhAhVSHqwKHXhxA1sQ_AUIDigB) for jpg's in your media library.

To do this, I created a custom meta box which lets you draw the depth map using canvas/js, on the post edit page.

However in order to see what you're doing, you need to be able to draw ontop of the featured image your making the depth map for.

I can get the posts current featured image according to the database, but if the user changes the image without clicking update, and then goes on to create a depth map I would load up the old image.

I know I can ask people to update the post to work with the new image, but that feels slow and yucky.

So I thought I would use JS to find out what picture is currently in the featured image box and just listen for it to change.

However I realize between wordpress 4.x and 5.0 some big changes were made to the editor and all the html/tags surrounding the featured image are different.

I could write use case logic for both of these, but this is starting to feel like a serious hack, and I'm not even sure how compatible it would be with other plugins/versions of wordpress I don't test it on.

Is there any standard way in wordpress to listen for a change to that image, like maybe listen to the wp.media object somehow?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:

I found a [git hub conversation](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/9340) about this exact topic. Turns out before Gutenberg you could use this code to log every media event in the console.log

```
wp.media.frame.on('all', function(e) { console.log(e); });
```

Unfortunately with Gutenberg that is no longer possible. Still looking for a way that works with both.